# it is possible to turn a seft-owned variable to static lifetime?

Tags: rust

this happens to me a lot of times, for example,

```
pub struct EmailTemplateMessageBuilder(Translator);

impl EmailTemplateMessageBuilder {
    pub fn new(locale: LanguageIdentifier)  -> Self{
        Self(Translator::new(locale))
    }

    fn render<C>(&self, template_name: &str, email_template: &EmailTemplate, context: &C) -> String {
        let mut template_engine = TinyTemplate::new();
        let translator = self.0;

       //The add_formatter method below has signature: 
       // pub fn add_formatter<F>(&mut self, name: &'template str, formatter: F)
       // where
       // F: 'static + Fn(&Value, &mut String) -> Result<()>

        template_engine.add_formatter(
            "trans", 
           |value: &Value, output: &mut String|  { 
                match value {
                    Value::String(s) => {
                        output.push_str(translator.trans_simple(s).as_ref()); 
        
                        Ok(())
                    }
                    _ => panic!("Unable to translate {}", value),
                }
        });

          template_engine.render("default", context)
            .expect(&format!("Enable to render email template {}", template_name))
    }
}
```

Since the EmailTemplateMessageBuilder struct owns the translator, I know its lifetime outlives the template_engine variable, so does to the closure,
the translator variable should be always valid when its get called.  it seems I need a way to turn self-owned reference to 'static lifetime.

Note:

- The Translator can't implement Copy trait, because it depends on other variable which is not copied.
- This code is run in the same thread, no future, no multiple threads.

Comment: Is it possible you're looking for [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html)? It works like `Copy` but must be invoked explicitly and is available on a lot more types.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, yes, is thiss the only way?

Comment: If you own `self`, you can move a value out of it. But as long as the value is owned by `self,` it's going to be freed when `self` is freed. End of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems I need a way to turn self-owned reference to 'static lifetime.

That's what `Rc` is for. Define the struct as `EmailTemplateMessageBuilder(Rc<Translator>)`, and define `translator` as `self.0.clone()`. The `clone()` only clones the pointer and increases the reference count, so it's cheap. Finally, make the closure `move`, so it owns all captured data.

Comment: I see,  thank you  so much,  finally I  understand Rc.